# Cannot get data from firebase to be appended to array in order

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from my firebase cloud storage and put it into an array, in order. I understand the async nature of firebase and that I need to use dispatch groups to wait for data return. I have tried looking at solutions here but cannot get my code to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
func ReadMyData() {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    let data = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document("LdGcPDsSVEtYyrGIHR1D")

        data.getDocument { (document, error) in

            for item in (document?.data())! {
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                self.Array.append(item.key)
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
            dispatchGroup.wait()
    }

    print(Array)

}
```

Comment: *dispatch groups to wait for data return* is not necessarily accurate. Depends on what you are doing with your data and when. For example, if you want to populate a dataSource array for a tableView, you can load up the dataSouce within the Firestore closure and then call tableView.reloadData(). No dispatch needed. The question is you want them in order. What is the order? By last name? By uid? By when then signed up for your app?

Comment: Please note that `print(Array)` will execute before the Array is loaded due to the asynchronous nature of Firestore and will generally print nil. Move it after your for loop. Also, just remove the dispatch calls as they are not needed and your data will be in order (you didn't specify how you wanted the data ordered) however, relying on them to be in order may be a problem. Put them into a dictionary and the order won't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use completion instead of DispatchGroup. You will use it way more in the future, so you better master it:

P.S: Name your functions names and variables names in a camel case way. It is the norm in Swift language.

```
func readMyData(completion: () -> ()) {

    let data = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document("LdGcPDsSVEtYyrGIHR1D")

    data.getDocument { (document, error) in

        for item in (document?.data())! {
            self.myArray.append(item.key) //using Array as the name of an array is bad practice.
        }
        print(myArray)
        completion()
    }
}
```

When you will call this function, you will be able to do your next action when the completion is called, thus ensuring that all your data manipulations, in this case, appending to your array, is completed before doing the next actions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, new to using this. I posted this as an answer. I initially wanted an ordered array due to confusion with the asynchronous call of data from firebase. However the solution provided, along with using objects in strays solved my problem. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for your help!